# Laravel 5 issues uploading/saving pdf

Tags: pdf, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6, jQuery 3.3.1, bootstrap 3.3.7, and PHP 7.1.4

I need to be able to allow users to upload files and pictures, basically jpg, gif, png, and pdf. I am using the public disk and storing the files in storage/app/public/folder_name where folder_name is defined in an env file

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
PO_FILE_FOLDER=purchase_orders
INSURANCE_FILE_FOLDER=insurance
NOTE_FILE_FOLDER=notes
RENTAL_AGREEMENT_FILE_FOLDER=rental_agreements
SIGNATURES=signatures
```

They are then defined in config/app

```
'insurance_file_folder' => env('INSURANCE_FILE_FOLDER', ''),
'po_file_folder' => env('PO_FILE_FOLDER', ''),
'note_file_folder' => env('NOTE_FILE_FOLDER', ''),
'rental_agreement_file_folder' => env('RENTAL_AGREEMENT_FILE_FOLDER', ''),

'max_image_width' => env('MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH', 500),
'filesystem_driver' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
```

When I upload image files they upload to the appropriate folder but when I try to upload pdf files the system creates a new folder named as what I'm naming the file and the pdf is in the new folder with a random name. I'm using the exact same code to upload both images and pdf files so I can't figure out why it works for one but not the other.

Here is my controller code

```
public function store(PurchaseOrderRequest $poRequest, Customer $customer)
{
    $purchaseOrder = $customer->purchaseOrders()->create($poRequest->except('attachment'));

    if ($poRequest->hasFile('attachment')) {
        $purchaseOrder->saveFile(config('app.po_file_folder', ''), $poRequest->file('attachment'));
    }

    return redirect()->action('CustomerController@edit', $customer)->with('alert', 'Purchase Order created.');
}
```

My model PurchaseOrder saveFile code

```
public function saveFile($folder_name, $file)
{
    // if file submited then check if file already exists, if so delete file and create new file
    $file_name = $this->createFileName();
    File::removeFiles($folder_name.'/'.$file_name, FALSE);
    $file_name = $file_name.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = File::resize($file);
    $this->attachment_path = $folder_name.'/'.$file_name;
    Storage::disk(config('app.filesystem_driver', ''))->put($this->attachment_path, $file);

    $this->save();
}

public function createFileName()
{
    $file_name = 'po_'.$this->customer->code.'-'.$this->customer->id.'_'.$this->po_number.'-'.$this->id;
    return $file_name;
}
```

My File helper code

```
public static function resize($file)
{
   $resized_file = $file;

   if (strtolower($resized_file->getClientOriginalExtension()) != 'pdf') {
     // resize file if it is not pdf (file is photo)
     // get image size then resize largest size to size limit - dont upsize if image is smaller than max size
     list($width, $height) = getimagesize($resized_file);

     if ($width > $height) {
        $resized_file = Image::make($resized_file)->resize(config('app.max_image_width', ''), null, function ($constraint) {
             $constraint->aspectRatio();
             $constraint->upsize();
        })->encode($resized_file->getClientOriginalExtension(), 60);
     } else {
        $resized_file = Image::make($resized_file)->resize(null, config('app.max_image_width', ''),function ($constraint) {
             $constraint->aspectRatio();
             $constraint->upsize();
        })->encode($resized_file->getClientOriginalExtension(), 60);
     }
   }

   return $resized_file;
}

public static function removeFiles($file_name, $ext_included = FALSE)
{
   if ($ext_included == TRUE) {
     // remove specific file
     if (Storage::disk(config('app.filesystem_driver', ''))->exists($file_name)) {
         Storage::delete($file_name);
     }
   } else {
      // remove file with any extension
      $ext = array('.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');

      for ($cnt = 0; $cnt <= 4; ++$cnt) {
         if (Storage::disk(config('app.filesystem_driver', ''))->exists($file_name.$ext[$cnt])) {
            Storage::delete($file_name.$ext[$cnt]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I realize the code may be a little confusing use the env variables but I'm trying to limit the pain in the event I need to change the folder name or move the files outside of the app. The application will have very few users maybe 3 or 4 and I don't anticipate a lot of files being uploaded which is why I'm storing the files in the application structure.

This is my first Laravel app and I put this code together using the docs and many a many different tutorials. It took a while but eventually I got it to work for images. So if you see things that don't look standard or good practice I welcome any pointers.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use two different approaches to saving files in the system based on if the file was an image or pdf. I do some processing (resizing) on images before putting them into my storage folders with Intervention Image. This in turn returns a different object type than the raw uploaded file, because of this some of the commands to add the file (after processing) will not work.

So if I'm storing a pdf file I use:

```
$file->storeAs($folder_name, $file_name, config('app.filesystem_driver', ''));
```

If I'm storing an image that I have used Intervention Image on then I use:

```
Storage::disk(config('app.filesystem_driver', ''))->put($this->attachment_path, $file);
```

I couldn't find one command that worked for both so I just check the extension before storing. Not sure if this is the "right way" but it got the job done.